# How can I spread content from an ancient text without governmental supervision?

Tags: society, information, knowledge

I am a social justice warrior on a crusade against my nation. For decades, I have watched our leaders ruthlessly expand their power under the guise of "protecting democratic interests around the world". To this end, they have used excuses to justify their fascist policies and unjust wars in foreign countries, pulling a wool over the public's eyes with constant lies and deception. The most recent violation of basic human dignity is suppression of knowledge from a book called the Necromonion.

This book was written centuries ago by an Arab named Abdul Alhazred, and has been passed down through the generations into the hands of certain individuals today. It supposedly contains vast information of the cosmos, giving access to technologies beyond our wildest dreams. The knowledge inside it can create a renaissance, ending diseases or social ills, finally leading us to a equal society. However, the government has forbidden research into studying this text, and has taken draconian measures to prevent it from falling into the hands of the public.

The authorities, in tandem with nations from around the planet through supranatural world organizations, have banned printing of the book and have required companies such as Google, facebook, twitter, yahoo, etc to remove all traces regarding the necromonion from their search engines, citing dubious and ridiculous  claims such as "causing eventual insanity among humans", "ancient and unknowable gods", or "things that mortal men were not meant to know or look upon". Websites have been censored or taken down  Distribution of the material or even owning a copy of the book comes with hefty, mandated 20yr sentences, with further regulation upon release.

This is another indication of the political elite criminalizing information and hoarding it to themselves preventing true power from reaching the hands of the people. The public deserve to know, and it is my duty to spread the contents of the text to as many people as possible, as soon as possible. But with all the regulation and not knowing who to trust, marching toward this goal has been made difficult.

How can I make this possible?

Comment: You might at least have the decency to credit H P Lovecraft.  You are in fact asking if you can avoid censorship in a digital world if "the authorities" (who can't even agree between each other on what names to give committees) conspire together to prevent people accessing this book.  The answer to this is trivially "yes you can avoid censorship" because at worst there is word of mouth, even if it has to be whispered.

Comment: I'm VTCing as story based, because you are asking for a plot to allow you to make this happen, or so I read it.

Comment: *Necromonion*, seriously? An "ancient text", even one written by an Arab, can very resonably be known by a Greek name, but is *The Little Dead Solitude* (or maybe *The Small Loneliness of the Dead*, hmmm) a reasonable name? Or is there another reasonable Greek meaning for this word? Honestly, if I came across a text titled *Necromonion* and pretenting to be a repository of ancient wisdom I would call it a hoax.

Comment: I'm VTC as story-based too. There's no shortage of ways to distribute information illegally in the contemporary society - torrents, darknet, viruses, spamming by mail and from duplicate accounts in social media. It's not a problem to get the copy of the book on the lot of computers, the problem is to interest people to read it. And the exact choices of a person who tries to market the book and, in the other corner, the government make the story itself. (Say, is the government banning the book officially? That's the best way to get a decent number of people looking for that book).

Comment: I wonder if for some of these questions it would be good to have a VTC:LMGTFY option. I feel like it would be easier to find the answer than it would be to write a question here. I've added an answer just to be helpful, but srsly.

Answer (score 7):

One word: [Samizdat](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Samizdat).

I mean, seriously, illegal and shady printing and distribution has been a thing since *printing* has been a thing. Attempts to totally stamp out information distribution never work because, y'know, you can't watch everyone all the time and even a powerful totalitarian state will always have people prepared to risk everything to oppose it.

And that's just print. If you're prepared to drago yourself kicking and screaming into the 20th century, there's pirate radio and hand-distributed audio recordings (and even video tapes, if you can imagine that).

"*Information wants to be free*", etc etc.

Comment: *you can't watch everyone all the time* Is that a black helicopter I hear on the wind ... ? :-)